# How to detect when ScrollPane finishes scrolling

Tags: java, javafx

I want to detect when a ScrollPane finishes scrolling in my application, to disable some triggers when moving than help make the UI a bit cleaner.  I found a trigger for when it moves, but I can't find a trigger or way to determine when it stops

```
scrollPane.vvalueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
          @Override
          public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
              if (oldValue!=newValue) {
                  isScrolling = true;
              } else {
                  isScrolling = false;
              }
          }
        });
```

Comment: ChangeListeners are only notified only if the value changed, so you never reach the else block (as you noticed ;) Don't quite understand what you are after, please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Obviously I know that, the problem is that there's not a listener or quick way to access the precise stopping point like there is for detecting a change.
The accepted answer works, but it's a little more complicated than the method for detecting a change.

Comment: then why do you implement that do-nothing else block if it's so _obvious_ that it's never reached? want to confuse your co-worker?

Comment: If you don't have an actual answer, maybe don't bother responding to things just to nitpick :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to do this with an external Timer or javafx.animation.Timeline. Use Timeline if you're changing the UI.

Set a flag such as `lastScrollSeen` as a datetime and trigger that timer when you first get a scroll event. Update `lastScrollSeen` every time you get another scroll event, and at periodic intervals (using the Timer/Timeline) see if enough time has elapsed without an additional scroll event for you to be comfortable that the user has finished scrolling.

At that point do your work to disable your triggers and clear the flag and timer.